# how to display data in view file

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to get data of a user(first_name, last_name, phone, email) from the session.

```
public function actionIndex(){
   $query = User::findOne(Yii::$app->session['user']['id']);

  return $this->render('index', ['query' => $query]);
}
```

I tried using the DetailView::Widget in the view file but it's not cutting any ice.
Can someone help me how to display this data in view file in a list?

```
Viewfile:

    echo DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'title',               // title attribute (in plain text)
        'description:html',    // description attribute in HTML
        [                      // the owner name of the model
            'label' => 'Owner',
            'value' => $model->user->last_name,
        ],
        //'created_at:datetime', // creation date formatted as datetime
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->render('index', ['model' => $query]); }
```

Change key `**query**` to `model`. Or in view change `$model` to `$query`.

If user is logged, and you use app/model/user model you can use:

```
$user = \Yii::$app->user->identity;
echo $user->last_name;
echo $user->id;
```

Viewfile:

```
    echo DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'title',               // title attribute (in plain text)
        'description:html',    // description attribute in HTML
        [                      // the owner name of the model
            'label' => 'Owner',
            'value' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->last_name,
        ],
        //'created_at:datetime', // creation date formatted as datetime
    ],
]);
```

Comment: $user = \Yii::$app->user->identity;
echo $user->last_name;
echo $user->id;
where do it put this code?